# Code Coverage when using NUnit to test unmanaged C++

Tags: c++, unit-testing, nunit, unmanaged

My team is currently using CppUnit for all our unmanaged C++ unit tests but I'm toying with the idea of transitioning to NUnit through either GenTestAsm (pure C#) or C++/CLI.  Either way, what consequences would I face on the Code Coverage front with either of these approaches?

We currently use PureCoverage to instrument our unmanaged unit test executables for collecting coverage data.  Would we still be able to do this or is there another tool?  Or would we lose code coverage visibility all together?

Comment: It could be, but I don't think we're the first team to want code coverage on our unit tests.